# Fail to convert var-char array to int array in vertica SQL

Tags: arrays, vertica

when trying to convert varchar array to an integer array like that:

`cast(array['1','2','3'] as int[])`

the query works just fine- receiving [1,2,3]

but when trying to use the following query I'm getting :

```
select cast(try as int[]) final
from (
         select STRING_TO_ARRAY('[1,2,3,4,5,6]', ',') try
     ) a
```

I'm getting
'[Vertica]VJDBC ERROR: Failed to find conversion function from varchar[] to int[]'

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Vertica are you using?

Comment: 10.0. Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything more, I would use a Vertica database for what it is good at:

Explode arrays into rows, and take it from there. It's much more efficient in all possible use cases:

```
WITH input AS (
         SELECT STRING_TO_ARRAY('[1,2,3,4,5,6]', ',') try
)
,
i(i) AS (
          SELECT 0
UNION ALL SELECT 1
UNION ALL SELECT 2
UNION ALL SELECT 3
UNION ALL SELECT 4
UNION ALL SELECT 5
)
,
unpivot AS (
  SELECT
    i
  , try[i]
  , REPLACE(try[i],'"','')::INT AS array_el_as_int
  FROM input CROSS JOIN i
)
SELECT
 *
FROM unpivot;
```

And you get:

```
 i | array_el | array_el_as_int  
---+----------+-----------------
 0 | "1"      |               1
 1 | "2"      |               2
 2 | "3"      |               3
 3 | "4"      |               4
 4 | "5"      |               5
 5 | "6"      |               6
```